# Как прочитать JSON объект в Java

Tags: java, json

Я пытаюсь прочитать `JSON` объект в `Java` (только начинаю с `JSON`)

`JSON` файл:

```
[
  {
    "id": 0,
    "server": "Singleplayer",
    "dimension": 0,
    "position": {
      "coords_1": -214,
      "coords_2": 76,
      "coords_3": 330
    },
    "name": "d",
    "time": "08:49:14 08/11/2020"
  }
]
```

Как я могу прочитать `position`?

Comment: https://devqa.io/how-to-parse-json-in-java/

Answer (score 0):

Для примера создание юзера из 3 параметров: имя, фамилия и зарплата. Примерно так, думаю разберётесь

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/add")
  public class ServletAdd extends HttpServlet {
  Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
        
    @Override
            protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
                StringBuffer jb = new StringBuffer();
                String line;
                try {
                    BufferedReader reader = req.getReader();
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                        jb.append(line);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e){
                    System.out.println("Error");
                }
                JsonObject jobj = gson.fromJson(String.valueOf(jb), JsonObject.class);
        
                req.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        
                String name = jobj.get("name").getAsString();
                String surname = jobj.get("surname").getAsString();
                double salary = jobj.get("salary").getAsDouble();

                User user = new User(name, surname, salary);
                pw.print(gson.toJson(user));
        }
```

===========================================================================

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Создать нового пользователя</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="add">
    <label>Имя:
        <input type="text" name="name">
    </label>
    <label>Фамилия:
        <input type="text" name="surname">
    </label>
    <label>Зарплата:
        <input type="text" name="salary">
    </label>
    <button type="submit">Создать</button>
</form>

<a href="index.jsp">Домой</a>

</body>
</html>
```